# NSString floatValue, not working with large numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

This is my code for converting a NSString to a float:

```
NSString *userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [user id]];

float u = [userID floatValue];

NSLog(@" Float: %f", u);
NSLog(@"String: %@", [user id]);
```

And this is in my log:

```
 Float: 100005150982144.000000
String: 100005153311676
```

What am I doing wrong? I have test using NSNumberFormatter to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take double value:

```
double doubleValue=[userID doubleValue];
NSLog(@" Float: %lf", doubleValue);
NSLog(@"String: %@", [user id]);
```

Reason: Your value surpassed float value's range.

Comment: @H2CO3 : I was enjoying cricked, a debutant scoring 185* with Aussiess. I checked and this question wasn't attempted by anyone, So I dived here. Do you like cricket?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Honestly, I haven't yet played that sport. But I like golf, and that's close.